# перемещение данных из массива в массив по клику мышки по соответствующему элементу HTML

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, click

Помогите разобраться что и за чем делать.
Итак, у меня есть два массива (один с данными, другой пустой):

```
let PC_Hand = [a, b, c];
let PC_Avant_Grade = new Array();
```

Есть HTML-елементы, которые отображают содержимое этих массивов:

```
const PCHand = document.querySelectorAll('.comp-card-hand'); 
const PCAG = document.querySelectorAll('.comp-card-avantgrade');

function Print_Hand(arr, div) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    while (div[i].firstChild) {
      div[i].removeChild(div[i].firstChild);
  };
  div[i].appendChild(arr[i].getHTML());
  }
};

Print_Hand(PC_Hand, PCHand);
Print_Hand(PC_Avant_Grade, PCAG);
```

Данные из массива выводятся в указанный элемент HTML-документа, путем создания в нем дочернего div-элемента.

Итак, что мне нужно: я хочу переместить элемент PC_Hand[i] на позицию PC_Avant_Grade[y] через клик мыши по дочернему элементу PCHand[i] и элементу PCAG[y].

Я пробовал сделать нечто вроде этого:

```
// обьявил глобальные переменные для запоминания значения и номера элемента массива, который нужно переместить
let index = 0;
let k = new Cards();

//Сделал проверну на наличие дочерних элементов и если они есть, то дал им функцию, которую нужно выполнить при клике.
if (PCHand.hasChildNodes()) {
    var children = PCHand.childNodes;
    var i = 0;
// вот у меня проблема: как выйти из ребенка на номер элемента родителя?
    children[i].onclick = function() {
      k = PC_Hand[i]; // запоминаю значение массива по номеру
      delete PC_Hand[i]; // удалю значение из массива. 
    }
  }
};

// далее опять функция клика, которая должна определить номер элемента массива по клику по соответствующему диву и записать туда запомненное значение k.
PCAG[index].onclick = function() {
  PC_Avant_Grade[index] = k;
  Print_Hand(PC_Rearguard, PCRG);
}
```

Я понимаю, что в последнем фрагменте кода скорее всего полный бред, однако самостоятельно понять, что не так, у меня не получается. Думаю, возможно, стоит использовать TargetListener, однако понятия не имею, как его сюда запихнуть...

`Cards` выглядит так:

```
class Cards {
  constructor(suits, attak, attaktipe, accuracy, health, defence, speed, dexterity) {
    this.suits = suits;
    this.attak = attak;
    this.attaktipe = attaktipe;
    this.accuracy = accuracy;
    this.health = health;
    this.defence = defence;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.dexterity = dexterity;
  };
  getHTML() {
    const CardDIV = document.createElement('div');
    CardDIV.innerText = this.suits;
    CardDIV.classList.add("card");
    CardDIV.dataset.value = `${this.attak}  ${this.defence}  ${this.speed} ${this.health}`;
    return CardDIV;
  };
};
```

Код изначального HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, instant-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/battle.css">
    <title>Card game</title>
    <script src="./js/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

      <div class="battle">

      <div class="comp-card-hand card-slot">Hand 1</div>
      <div class="comp-card-hand card-slot">Hand 2</div>
      <div class="comp-card-hand card-slot">Hand 3</div>

      <div class=""></div>
      <div class="comp-card-avantgrade card-slot">line 1-1</div>
      <div class="comp-card-avantgrade card-slot">line 1-2</div>
      <div class="comp-card-avantgrade card-slot">line 1-3</div>

      <div class="text-2"><button id="hider" onclick="Start()"> Start </button> <button id="hider2" onclick=""> Next </button></div>

      <div class="player-card-hand card-slot">hand 1</div>
      <div class="player-card-hand card-slot">hand 2</div>
      <div class="player-card-hand card-slot">hand 3</div>
      <div class=""></div>

      <div class="player-card-avantgrade card-slot">avant-garde 1</div>
      <div class="player-card-avantgrade card-slot">avant-garde 2</div>
      <div class="player-card-avantgrade card-slot">avant-garde 3</div>
      <div class=""></div>


      </div>
      <script src="./js/battle.js"></script>
    </div><!-- Battle -->



</body>
</html>
```

Вот еще скрин того, как это отображается в браузере (может это поможет понять, что я хочу сделать):

1. Это изначальное состояние:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. А это состояние с заполненным массивом `PC_Hand`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот я хочу кликом мышки выбрать, например (красные), элемент `militia` в `hand1` и переместить его в элемент `line 1-3`, то есть переместить значение элемента `PC_Hand[1]` в элемент `PC_Avant_Grade[3]`. Ключевой момент состоит в том, что я хочу не просто переместить созданный `div` от одного родителя к другому, а именно переписать значения из одного массива в другой, при этом кликая мышкой по соответствующим `div` элементам.

Comment: _как выйти из ребенка на номер элемента родителя?_ — из текущего элемента можно через свойство `parentNode` получить родителя. Не понятно, что означает "номер элемента родителя". Родитель может быть только один

Comment: От куда должно браться значение `y` для `PC_Avant_Grade[y]` и `PCAG[y]` если изначально элементов в `PCAG` может не быть?

Comment: Можно пример начального HTML?

Comment: Можно код или краткое описание того, чем является `Cards`?

Comment: @7-zete-7 добавил код 'Cards'.

Comment: @7-zete-7 Родители есть по умолчанию в коде самого HTML элемента, а дети уже создаются внутри них с помощью js.

Comment: @7-zete-7 `y` - это по идее должен быть порядковый номер, как `i` в циклах. `PC_Avant_Grade[y]` значения четко определены их три штуки. По идее в массиве `PCAG` даже если он пустой так же должно быть 3 элемента (в смысле по умолчанию в нем должно быть три пустых элемента, а уже затем в них будут добавляться данные из массива 1)

Comment: @7-zete-7 добавил интересующую меня часть изначального HTML кода

Comment: @7-zete-7 так же добавил скрины с браузера и пояснение, что я хочу с этим счатьем сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мое решение написано с нуля, но я думаю Вы сможете использовать эту логику у себя. Просто у меня вместо 4 чисел (объекта) - одно число и нет класса карты, но его можно добавить. Я постарался все прокоментировать.

Основная идея в том что я опираюсь на данные из массива, данные на картах просто отрисовываю, все действия только с массивами, со страницы я получаю только карты и их группы.

Так же у меня есть объект `allowMoveFromTo` который описывает какие перемещения между группами разрешены а какие нет, (из нижней сейчас нельзя в верхнюю и обратно, а также из группы нельзя в нее же) вы можете править логику игры.

Так же в игре `0` у меня считается пустым местом куда можно перемещать карту но сам `0` нельзя перемещать, карту на карту тоже нельзя перемещать - только на пустое место. Карта подсвечивается белым, место подсвечивается желтым.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main') 
const pcHandCards =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.hand-pc .card'))
const pcLineCards =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.line-pc .card'))
const playerHandCards =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.hand-player .card'))
const playerLineCards =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.line-player .card'))

// тут задается откуда куда можно перемещать карты
const allowMoveFromTo = {
  'hand-player':'line-player',
  'line-player':'hand-player', 
  'hand-pc':'line-pc',  
  'line-pc':'hand-pc'  
}

let activeFromCard = null; 
let activeToCard = null;
let activeFromGroup = 'hand-player'
let activeToGroup = 'line-player'

const pcHandArray = new Array(1,2,3)  
const pcLineArray = new Array(0,0,0)  

const playerHandArray = new Array(4,5,6)  
const playerLineArray = new Array(0,0,0)  

const arrayByGrop = {
  'hand-player': playerHandArray,
  'line-player': playerLineArray,
  'hand-pc': pcHandArray,
  'line-pc': pcLineArray
}

// отрисовка одной группы
const drawGroup = (view, data) => {
  view.forEach((card, index) => {
    card.textContent = data[index]
  })
}

// отрисовка всех групп
const drawCards = () => {
  drawGroup(pcHandCards, pcHandArray)
  drawGroup(pcLineCards, pcLineArray)
  drawGroup(playerHandCards, playerHandArray)
  drawGroup(playerLineCards, playerLineArray)
}

const moveAction = (fromIndex, toIndex) => {
  //console.log(activeFromGroup, '>>>', activeToGroup)

  // выбор участвующих массивов
  const fromArr = arrayByGrop[activeFromGroup]
  const toArr = arrayByGrop[activeToGroup]

  // перемещение данных
  const value = fromArr[fromIndex]
  toArr[toIndex] = value
  fromArr[fromIndex] = 0

  drawCards()
}

// получение индекса карты (0 - 2) в своей группе  (hand, line)
const getIndex = (target) => {
  const parent = target.parentNode
  return  Array.from(parent.children).indexOf(target)
}

// проверяет разрешено ли движение
const isAllowedMove = () => {
  return  (allowMoveFromTo[activeFromGroup] === activeToGroup)
}

// проверка что карта пустая по массиву
const isCardEmpty = (target) =>  {
  const parent = target.parentNode
  const cardGroup = parent.className
  const cardIndex = Array.from(parent.children).indexOf(target)
  return arrayByGrop[cardGroup][cardIndex] === 0
}

const selectFirstCard = (target) => {
  // не выделяем пустые карты
  if (!isCardEmpty(target) /* target.textContent !== '0' */) {
    activeFromCard = target
    activeFromCard.classList.add('active-from')
  }
}

const selectSecondCard = (target) => {
  if ( !isCardEmpty(target) /*target.textContent !== '0' */) {
    // если вторая карта не пустая выходим
    return
  }
  if (activeFromCard === target ){
      return // если та же карта выходим  
  } 
  activeToCard = target
  activeToCard.classList.add('active-to') 
  // из какой группы
  activeFromGroup = activeFromCard.parentNode.className
  // в какую группу  
  activeToGroup = activeToCard.parentNode.className
  if (!isAllowedMove()) return // выход при запрещенном действии 
  moveAction (getIndex(activeFromCard), getIndex(activeToCard))  
}

const newSelectionStart = (target) => {
  activeFromCard.classList.remove('active-from') 
  activeToCard.classList.remove('active-to') 
  // cнова выбираем первую если она не пустая 
  if ( !isCardEmpty(target) /*target.textContent !== '0' */) {
    activeFromCard = target 
    activeFromCard.classList.add('active-from')
    activeToCard = null
  }  
}

const selectCard = (target) => {
  // выбираем первую карту
  if (activeFromCard === null && activeToCard === null){
    selectFirstCard(target)
    return
  }
  // выбираем вторую карту
  if (activeFromCard !== null && activeToCard === null){
    selectSecondCard(target)
    return
  }
  // когда две карты выбраны
  if (activeFromCard !== null && activeToCard !== null){
    newSelectionStart(target)
  }
}

// добавляем делегирование событий
main.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  if (!target.classList.contains('card')) return
  selectCard(target)
})
// первая отрисовка
drawCards()
```

```css
.card {
  height: 80px;
  width: 50px;
  border : 1px solid gray;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.active-from{
  box-shadow: snow 5px 5px 5px ;
} 

.active-to{
  box-shadow: rgba(225, 240, 12, 0.89) 5px 5px 5px ;
} 


section.pc .card {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .50);
}
section.player .card {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .50);
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;  
  background-color: #87dad6;
}  

section.pc, section.player {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}  

section.player {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}  

.hand-pc,
.line-pc,
.hand-player,
.line-player{
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="pc">
    <div class="hand-pc">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="line-pc">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>  
  </section>  
  <section class="player">
    <div class="hand-player">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="line-player">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>  
  </section>  
</main>
```

Comment: Спасибо за код в полном обьеме, анализируя его я смогу многому научиться. Этот ответ очень близок к тому, что я хочу сделать. Постараюсь адаптировать его к своему коду, если все сработает, будет просто замечательно. Скорее всего в процессе у меня могут возникнуть дополнительные вопросы, надеюсь, Вы не будете против ответить на них.

Comment: Да, разумеется обращайтесь, рад что вам понравился мой вариант.

Comment: у меня вопрос: я заметил, что Вы используете элемент `main`. Это обязательное условие или его можно заменить, например, на `div`? Просто у меня все завязано на дивах и я не уверен, что использование майн хорошая идея, так как он может быть лишь один на документ и вполне возможно, что он понадобиться мне в будущем.

Comment: Можно заменить, на див, но один человек, а именно Вадим Макеев называет эту болезнь дивиозом))) в общем тут решайте сами, главное тогда селектор выберите подходящий, можете например класс ему задать 'main', айдишники обычно редко используют в css - они для js.

Comment: добрый день еще раз... у меня возникло несколько вопросов по Вашему коду в процессе его адаптации к своему, хотелось бы обсудить это с Вами, если можно. Но здесь это проблематично, как отправить Вам личное сообщение я не нашел. Если Вы не против, отпишитесь, как можно с Вами связаться для более детального общения по Вашему коду и его адаптации под мои нужды.

Comment: написал Вам в telegram